# Atan2 identities

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I was reading through the definition of $atan2$ function from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)

For convenience

$$
\text{atan2}(y,x) =
\begin{cases}
\text{atan}(y/x) & x >0 \\
\pi + \text{atan}(y/x) & x < 0, y \geq 0 \\
-\pi + \text{atan}(y/x) & x < 0, y < 0 \\
\pi/2 & x = 0, y > 0 \\
-\pi/2 & x = 0, y < 0
\end{cases}
$$

I was trying to find a relationship between $\text{atan2}(y,x)$ and $\text{atan2}(-y,x)$
and I've derived

$$
\text{atan2}(y,x) + \text{atan2}(-y,x) = 2\pi \chi_{(-\infty,0)\times(-\infty,0]}(x,y)
$$

Where $\chi_A(x,y)$ is $1$ if $(x,y) \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.
My question is is the identity above valid? What I did to derive was literally computing based $\text{atan2}(-y,x)$ for all the cases above when $y$ flips sign and adding the original expression and the one with the $y$'s sign flipped together. It mostly makes sense to me except that corner case $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct. For $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$ is $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ the angle between the positive x-axis and the ray from the origin to the point $(x, y)$ in the Euclidean plane, with $-\pi < \operatorname{atan2}(y, x) \le \pi$.

The points $(x, -y)$ and $(x, y)$ are symmetric with respect to the x-axis. If the points lie on the negative real axis ($x<0$ and $y=0)$ then
$$
 \operatorname{atan2}(y, x) + \operatorname{atan2}(-y, x) = \pi + \pi = 2 \pi \, .
$$
Otherwise the angles between the x-axis and the rays to these points have the same magnitude, but opposite sign in the range $(-\pi, \pi)$, so that
$$
\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) + \operatorname{atan2}(-y, x) = 0\, .
$$

In your notation that would be
$$
\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) + \operatorname{atan2}(-y, x) = 2\pi \chi_{(-\infty,0)\times \{ 0 \}}(x,y) \, .
$$

Comment: So it should be $0$ for any pair $x,y$ then? I probably did the math wrong then but there were two corner cases that probably I didn't consider correctly.

Comment: @user8469759: There was an error – hopefully correct now!

Comment: So there was a mistake in the interval for the $y$ variable.

Comment: @user8469759: Yes. The sum is $2 \pi$ only on the negative real axis, not in the complete third quadrant.